# In Delphi compiling a library produces an exe extension, is this correct?

Tags: delphi, dll

I have Delphi Seattle and when I change the "program" keyword in the project source file to "library", and compile/run, it produces an exe. Is this normal? In older copies of delphi it would automatically produce a DLL instead of an exe extension.

Is the solution to change some compiler option or project option setting? There is an output file extension setting, but I thought the compiler would take care of this automatically as soon as you change "program" to "library". In old Delphi 5 it worked.

This may affect other versions than just Seattle, have not tried...

Is this a bug?

Comment: You have to change the project type in your project settings.

Comment: Generally, it produces a `.dll` extension, like in older versions. Something in your setup must have changed that. Now if you started it as a normal program and then **changed** the code to `library`, it may not change that. You should start it as library to begin with.

Comment: Why don't you create a new project "library" and include your files in it ? I suppose you start with a program to test the code you create ?

Comment: I often start out a project as an Exe, then later decide it becomes a DLL, which, AFAIR in delphi 5/7 the compiler was smart enough to figure it all out.. Wondering if there is a way to do this in project settings somehow to make an existing exe project become a dll project.

Answer (score 0):

The executable extension is a project setting passed to the compiler, but if you want to control it from source, there's the [`$E` compiler directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Executable_extension_(Delphi))

Answer (score 0):

If you start a project as DLL, then the library template is used (the one with the long warning comment), and you automatically get the extension `.dll`.

If you, however, start a project as a normal program (e.g. a console program), the extension is `.exe`, and that doesn't automatically change if you change the keyword `program` to `library`. I don't think it did that in any earlier Delphi either.

So, to get a default `.dll` extension, use

> File → New → Other... → Delphi Projects → Dynamic-link Library

As already said, you can change the extension in the project options too:

> Project → Options... → Application → Output Settings → Target file extension

Or simply as `{$E DLL}` in the `.dpr` source code.

Comment: Thanks, - if I change just the extension, will the compiler be smart enough to actually compile it as a DLL though, or does it compile it as an Exe format just with a different extension... as that may be important. i.e. if it's just masquerading as a DLL but is actually truly a Exe just with dll extension.